i want to write a program that give a number as an input while this input is not -1
this program should be in the loop while the input is not -1 if the input is -1,the program should execute the average of inputs. I can't understand how to use variables and how can i execute the average.
this is my code
count = 0 
sum = 0
adad = input ('enter a number:')
for i in adad:
    print (i)
    while i != -1 :
      print (i)
      count = count + 1
      sum = sum + int(i)
print (sum / count)

but it can't show me the results that i want

input returns a string; a text. If you want a number, you need to convert it using int(...). Also, if you want to take multiple inputs, input needs to be inside the loop as well.

Hope this helps you.
count = 0
sum = 0
while True:
    user_input = int(input('Enter a number(-1 to end): '))
    if user_input ==  -1:
        break
    sum += user_input
    count += 1
print (sum / count)

I have initialized two variables for sum of the inputs and count of the inputs. Using a similar concept as do-while loop, which runs and checks the condition whether the number is -1, if it is then it breaks the while loop. The input is converted to integer using int(...)
You can also try the below code.
input_arr = []
while True:
    user_input = int(input('Enter a number(-1 to end): '))
    if user_input ==  -1:
        break
    input_arr.append(user_input)
print (sum(input_arr) / len(input_arr))


a = 0 #loop count
b = 0 #sum
x = 0 #input
while (x!=-1):
    x = int(input("enter a number: "))
    b = b+x
    a = a+1

print((b+1)/(a-1))


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

with while loop, you can keep continously take user input till -1 is not given and achive your goal with it as below
# your code goes here
count = 0
avg = 0
total_sum = 0
while True:
    user_input = int(input("enter a number: "))
    if user_input == -1:
        if count == 0: count = 1
        avg = total_sum / count
        break
    total_sum += user_input
    count += 1

print(f"avg is {avg}")

